# Máscara para campo input de tamanho variado com windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Como fazer uma mascara para email em uma aplicação Windows Forms ?
To usando o MaskedTextBox que para validar campos de tamanho fixo,  exemplo: **CEP** e **CPF** o problema é quando a mascara é de tamanho variado por exemplo o **email** ?

Comment: Você já deu uma olhada no Evento [Control.Validating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx) ??

Comment: Eu não conheço, mas vou pesquisar e dou um retorno.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a namespace `System.Text.RegularExpressions;` para gerar uma regra e efetuar o calculo da mesma onde desejar.

Criei um exemplo bem simples para exemplificar o uso da classe `Regex`, onde executo a regra dentro de um evento click, para mostra o uso da regra. Segue Imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode ver bem simples, mais conhecendo a namespace melhor você vai ver que as possibilidade são inúmeras.

- CPF: `"^(\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3}-\d{2})|(\d{11})$"`
- CEP: `^\d{5}-\d{3}$`
- EMAIL:
  `"^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$"`

Regra utilizada no exemplo:

```
Regex regra = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$");
```